# F# RX using a timer

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I am learning RX, and trying to port some code in C# to F#.
The following is C# example for using a timer:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Current Time: " + DateTime.Now);
var source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp();
using (source.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp)))
      {
       Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
       Console.ReadKey();
      }
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The following is my code trying to do the same:

```
#light
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Reactive.Subjects


printfn "Current Time: %A" DateTime.Now

let source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Timestamp()
source.Subscribe(fun x -> printfn "%A %A" x.Value x.Timestamp) |> ignore
```

But I got compiler errors:

> Error 1 Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

I don't know how what type is for `x.Value` and `x.Timestamp`.
By the way, I also don't know how to re-write using in C# here in F#.
Please show me the correct code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a "direct translation" into F# from C#:

```
open System
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq

printfn "Current Time: %A" DateTime.Now
let source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds      (1.0)).Timestamp()
using (source.Subscribe(fun (x:Timestamped<int64>) -> printfn "%A %A" x.Value x.Timestamp))
    (fun _ ->
        printfn "Press any key to unsubscribe"
        Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    )

printfn "Press any key to stop"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

When running allow it to pass 5 seconds prior to seeing how 1 sec Timer events begin flowing in.

**ADDENDUM**: Type of input argument in the lambda expression that, in turn, is the argument of `Iobservable.Subscribe()` is the type of values of `IObservable` that we call `Subscribe()` on, i.e the type of values constituing `IObservable` `source`.

In turn, `source` represents result of `Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan)` method that returns an observable sequence that produces a value at due time and then after each period. This sequence has type `IObservable<int64>`.

`Timestamp()` method, when being applied to `IObservable<int64>` yields `IObservable<Timestamped<int64>>`.

So, eventually our `source` is `IObservable` of type `Timestamped<int64>`, which the code snippet above reflects as explicit type of argument `x` of the anonymous function within `Subscribe()`.

Comment: Hi, Gene Belitski: Thank you very much, your code works!  But it is difficult for me to know the type of x, as in the C# code, the type is also missing.

Comment: @John: As explanation of types involved takes more space, than max allowed for a comment, I'm placing it as addendum to my original answer. For clarity you may want to track this chain of type conversions yourself using [System.Reactive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229356(v=VS.103).aspx) as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe isn't working because it's overloaded.  If you specify which overload to use then it works.

```
(source.Subscribe : (Timestamped<int64> -> unit) -> IDisposable)(fun x -> printfn "%A %A" x.Value x.Timestamp) |> ignore
```

If you use the Add method instead of Subscribe, then the type will resolve correctly.

```
printfn "Current Time: %A" DateTime.Now

let source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Timestamp()
source.Add(fun x -> printfn "%A %A" x.Value x.Timestamp)

printfn "Press any key to stop"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```